# Navigation Provider: Show items only if not logged in

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I search for a solution to hide menu items if a user is logged on within the navigation provider. A property for the obversely way is available: `requiresAuthentication`

Can anyone help me?

To inject the `AbpSession` within the navigation provider and check if `AbpSession.UserId.HasValue` doesn't work. I think the problem is that the navigation provider object is cached because the provider will not called on every request.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you are right. it's already cached. Why don't you do it in client side. You can create menu items in client-side. Use this namespace in javascript:

```
abp.nav.menus
```